# How can I empty this div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I write a div and set contenteditable is true, so it can be editable.

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

and first I wrote something in it like "hello"
open the console I see the code has changed to

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">hello</div>
```

but when I cleared the word I've input in this div and input something new in it again I saw the console, the code was like this:

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">
    "hello"
    ""
</div>
```

and The times that I delete is  `""` appears.

I've tried to `$("#editor").empty()` when detect `DOMNodeRemoved` but it didn't work....

How can I empty this div?

Comment: Working fine : http://jsfiddle.net/57524/13/

Comment: It actually works. Have you use other extension that wrap your div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use below code to empty your div container:

```
$("#editor").text('')
```

Here is sample code that clears the container for you:

```js
$('.clear').click(function(){
  $('#editor').text('')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">
    "hello"
    ""
</div>
<button class="clear">clear</button>
```

Comment: @dfsq - Would like to understand, how above sample code is not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

very simple

```
$('#editor').html('');
```

or

```
jQuery('#editor').html('');
```

try this

Comment: .empty() method removes not only child (and other descendant) elements, but also any text within the set of matched elements. This is because, according to the DOM specification, any string of text within an element is considered a child node of that element.

Comment: check your jQuery version

Answer (score 0):

`.html('')` will work in your case. `$('#editor').html('');`

To listen for changes we can use:

```
$("#editor").on('DOMNodeRemoved', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target, ' => removed');
});
```

See example:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
$('#editor').html('');
}, 1000);

$("#editor").on('DOMNodeRemoved', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target, ' => removed');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">
    "hello"
    ""
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
$("#editor").text(""); - If this selector is a label
$("#editor").val(""); - If this selector is a input control
```

Sameway you can do for multiple using class names

```
$(".editorClass").text("");
$(".editorClass").val("");
```